# Arguments passed "by name" in C#

Tags: c#, pass-by-name

The *Scala* programming language has a neat feature, called *pass by name arguments*, that allows some arguments to only be evaluated if required.

For example, it's possible to write a `while` loop using a *curried* method such as the following:

```scala
// This is Scala code. A simulated while loop
@scala.annotation.tailrec
def myWhile(condition: => Boolean)(actions: => Unit): Unit = {
  if(condition) {
    actions
    myWhile(condition)(actions)
  }
}
```

This method can be used like a regular `while` loop, thanks to *Scala*'s syntactic sugar, closures and—of particular interest here—the ability to pass expressions as function arguments, which are evaluated when referenced (as indicated by the `: => type` argument declaration).

For example, the following prints "Hello!" to the console ten times:

```scala
var i = 0
myWhile(i < 10) {
  println("Hello!")
  i += 1
}
```

For those who need to understand what is happening, the expression `i < 10` is evaluated each time `condition` appears inside the `if(...)` statement inside the method, similarly, `println("Hello!"); i += 1` is evaluated each time `actions` appears in the body of the method. When recursively calling `myWhile` for the next iteration, the expressions are passed as is, since the method requires expressions, not values. *Scala* terms these *pass by name* arguments.

If these arguments were passed by value instead, then `i < 10` would be passed to `myWhile` as `false`, while "Hello!" would be printed exactly once, `i` would be incremented once, and the loop would execute infinitely.

(*Scala* is primarily a *functional* language, and this code is not even close to being *FP*, but it's a simple example.)

My question is, is there a way to pass arguments in this way to a *C#* function? Also note that I'm restricted to using *C# 7.3*. :-(

Comment: Sorry, I did not get what your question is about, but in C# you can do this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vSUqqV

Comment: @Luuk Ha ha! Yes, I think I had already figured that out... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you can get somewhat close with [`` Func`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1) and [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=net-6.0):

```
void MyWhile(Func<bool> condition, Action action) {
  while (condition()) {
    action();
  }
}
```

and calling as:

```
int i = 0;
MyWhile(() => i < 10, () => {
  Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
  ++i;
});
```

The syntax is a bit different, but the idea is similar.

Comment: This, but it's `Func<bool>` , not `Function<bool>`.

Comment: @Heinzi thanks, too much Java programming :)

Comment: @knittl Thanks, just what I was looking for. Not quite as elegant, IMHO, but it does the job. Thanks!